# Jquery animation doesn't work properly with the list items

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a vertical list of items each with a delete button. When I click delete on one I want the ones beneath to slide up smoothly, at the moment they are jumping.

Here is the code below:

http://codepen.io/ovesyan19/pen/chDgy

**jQuery**

```
$("#tasks_list").on('click', "a", function(){
    var _li = $(this).parent("li");
    _li.addClass("remove").stop().slideUp(300, function(){
        _li.remove();
    });
    return false;
});
```

**CSS**

```
#tasks_list li.remove{
    -webkit-animation: collapse_item 300ms ease;
    animation: collapse_item 300ms ease;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    transform-origin: 50% 0%;
}

@keyframes collapse_item {
    0%      {-ms-transform: rotateX(0deg); transform: rotateX(0deg);}
    100%    {-ms-transform: rotateX(-90deg); transform: rotateX(-90deg);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes collapse_item {
    0%      {-webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);}
    100%    {-webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);}
}
```

Comment: I've edited your question to give some background to people answering. The more information you give the better the answer you'll get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually im not sure if you can do this using `li` because the elements are not actually animating , they are just being resorted , which means nothing like `margin` , `position` or `padding` is changing , but i think you can achieve the desired effect if you use divs , a plugin like shapeshift may help you as well.

http://mcpants.github.io/jquery.shapeshift/

Edit:

this is a quick solution i thought of , so hope it helps .

Hint:

you can remove the element after animation is over via `.remove()`

http://fiddle.jshell.net/prollygeek/8zs3L/1/

Comment: thanks for the help but I want to do it without plugins etc if it is possible

Comment: actually slip : https://pornel.net/slip/ . may be perfect for you , as i said you can do it without plugins , if you use divs , but why wasting time and do something already made ?

Comment: I want to do more by myself cause I study web development just about a month:)

Comment: if so you may start writing your own code , and ask for help when you have issues , my pleasure to help you anytime if you need help.

Comment: This code on CodePen is all mine, I wrote it by myself from the beginning to an end. Thanks for helping me!:)

Comment: I'll be very grateful and I'm not in hurry so I am waiting

Comment: this looks much more clearer and better working, thanks!